# Add component to every view

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my xamarin app I have custom control `<commonErrors/>` which shows all types of error responses from the server. Now I have a lot of views and I don't want to add this control to every single one.

Is it possible to add control to every current and new View?

Comment: why don't you build it into a custom popup?

Comment: Because I don't want to show errors in that way

Comment: You could add it through your code during runtime. You could iterate through every view. Is that what you are looking for? Please give us some more insights. How is your app structured? How are your views setup? What kind of control is your custom control?

Comment: For me, your question isn't clear. Add it to every view and show/hide by setting IsVisible true/false

Comment: Subclass ContentView and add your <commonErrors> to the derived ContentView. Use the enhanced ContentView for all your views

Comment: All your child ContentPage can inherit from a parent ContenPage which has custom control <commonErrors/>.